# Criteria Query: how to sort on value in Map collection?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I can't seem to find an example of how to do this, so any help will be appreciated.

My schema has an object that looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

  @Id private Integer id;

  private String handle;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @MapKey(name = "udkey")
  private Map<String, UserData>   attrs;

  // rest of stuff omitted 
}
```

and the referenced entity as:

```
@Entity
public class UserData implements Serializable {

  @Id private Integer id;

  private String udKey;

  private String udData;

  // rest of stuff omitted

}
```

So the map has a variable amount of data attributes associated with a given user, for example:

```
udKey       udData
"email"     "john.q.public@gmail.com"
"realname"  "john public"
"dob"       "1960/01/30"
```

(for the keys I actually use enum objects, but I am trying to simplify this example.)

The question is how do I sort the User table on (for example) the e-mail address in a Criteria Query?  I think I start as follows:

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> root = query.from(User.class);

    MapJoin<User, String, UserData> join = root.join(User_.attrs);

    Expression exp =  // what goes here?

    query.orderBy(builder.asc(exp));
```

I hope this is clear enough.  I guess the generic question is how do I construct a path into the map with a literal key ("email" in the example).   Again thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to order by the udData, but because it is a OneToMany you would need to filter out email in the where clause.  If some user do not have an email, you would need to outer join.

If you need to order by multiple of the keys, then you need to have multiple joins.

Comment: I think I could code the SQL statement -- to the effect that I would join the table, and predicate WHERE userdata.ukey = "email" and ORDER BY userdata.uddata.   I just don't know what that looks like in Criteria Query.   Am I going the wrong direction?